# Probability Distributions with Dependence on Time

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have studied some undergraduate level probability and statistics, and I am curious as to when we would have parameters of a probability distribution for  which are functions of another variable (e.g. time).

Normally we see a distribution e.g. $X  \sim N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$, with constant parameters.

My question really is in what level mathematics will I see something like $X \sim D(\mu(t), \sigma^{2}(t)), $ where $D $ is the distribution?

I ask this because I believe that if you were to construct some model of reality, more often than not the parameters may indeed change with time.

Has anyone had industry experience where the model has had parameters dependent on time?

Comment: Probability of snowfall on a given date.  Crowds at airports on given dates.  Traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of models you mention are ubiquitous in practical applications.

For example, a company might build a product prototype, and characterise it chief performance parameter in its as-new conditions via a distribution with a given mean and variance (or whatever parameters are most suitable for the said distribution).

Afterwards, they would often be interested in modelling how the performance parameters varies over time: the mean might drift, and its variance spread too.

As another example, models based on Brownian motion with drift (google it, if you wish) are vastly used in Financial Modelling: the mean value of a certain stocks will have a mean, drifting with time, and a variance, increasing too with time.